# How to set pixel / columns in amcharts 4

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

i have this chart
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3HvP.png)

and i want the pixel or columns in that chart total is 36 pixel in X axis, how to do that??

this is my code

```
let dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
        dateAxis.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true;
        dateAxis.strictMinMax = true;
        dateAxis.max = moment("23:59", "HH:mm").toDate().getTime();
```

i use dateAxis on x Axis

i have tried, but i haven't found the right method yet